# Deployment Issue When unpackWARs is false in tomcat7

Tags: tomcat7

I am trying to deploy my grails application in Tomcat 7.0.27

My application lib directory contains some properties file as well along with the Jars.
In tomcat server.xml, When I set unpackWARs false (compressed deployment), then apache-tomcat-7.0.27/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib directory contains only Jars not the properties files which I have in my application lib.
I also tried putting properties file in tomcat lib, But no lock.. . Is there any configuration in tomcat to troubleshoot this issue ?

Also when unpackWARs is false, there are only two folders lib and classes in apache-tomcat-7.0.27/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/. This is also creating a new problem as my application searches for some other folders also in WEB-INF. This works good with unpackWARs true.

Any help on the above two problems will really be appriceated

To overcome the above two problems, I can set unpackWARs true, but there is a problem in extracting the war. Suppose my war file name is ROOT.war and the ROOT folder is already existing in webapps, then the server starts do not extract the ROOT.war and my app goes up with the old ROOT folder.
What should be the best way to clean up existing extracted war folder ROOT ? For now, I am deleting the existing ROOT folder in the start up sctipt /etc/init.d/tomcat.

Should I set unpackWars true or false ?

Many many Thanks in advance..

The OS I am using is RHEL 5.2 .. Please let me know If you need more info

Regards,
Prashant Gupta

Answer (score 0):

just use unpackwars true and let tomcat replace the old directory and files, everyhting inside will be overwritten. No need to delete with start up script.

If you don't want to replace ROOT, don't call the file ROOT.war.

Comment: ROOT folder is not getting overwritten on server start up, If my war name is ROOT.war

Comment: I remeber having to manually delete the default tomcat root, which displays tomcat manager app, but after removing that it works fine.

Comment: But for multiple deployments of ROOT.war, I have to delete exploded ROOT directory manually for each deployment

Comment: May be the earlier versions of tomcat dont have this problem, But with tomcat 7.0.27 , I m facing this problem.

Comment: I am using tomcat 7 it works fine.  There is something wrong in your debug process or elsewhere. Does it work with a different named war file ?

Comment: I renamed ROOT.war to ABC.war and made an empty folder ABC in the same directory. Then also the server start did not delete the empty ABC folder.

Comment: No, but it replaces everything in the directory with all the new files. Which is fine thats what it is supposed to do.

Comment: But if it is empty, then it should have been filled

Comment: Yes, itq quite simple and it (tomcat 7) works. You copy a war file to webapps directory, when tomcat starts it unpacks that war file. are you sure your war file is being correctly made, and you have double checked your directry lcoations. Check yr logs also.

Comment: If my war file name is ROOT.war and an empty ROOT folder exists, then it deletes the empty folder and then explode the ROOT.war in ROOT folder

Comment: my ROOT folder is not empty every time. There happens periodic auto deployments of ROOT.war and also in the log, I see if the ROOT.war is already exploded, It does not get exploded again

Comment: your previous comment said the opposite. Tomcat 7 works as you would expect it to.

Comment: I was just testing the behavior of tomcat with empty ROOT folder

Comment: Thank u very much .. It would be great if we can discuss about the problem which I have explained in my query when unpackWARs is false